# What's the probability that more than 10 students will get their hw back?

Tags: probability

This question is confusing me...

> Students submitted their homework and now they will get them back randomly. What can you say about the probability that more than 10 of them will get their own homework back?

What's confusing me here is that i don't know anything about the total number of students. They're probably asking for some general answer.

Any direction?

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_n$ be the $n$-th derangement number, i.e., the number of permutations of $n$ without fixed points. Suppose that there are exactly $n$ students. Then there are $n!$ ways of distributing the homework to students such that every student get exactly one homework back. Among them, there are ${n\choose k}D_{n-k}$ ways such that exactly $k$ students get their own homework. Therefore, the desired probability of more than $10$ students getting their own homework is 
$$
p_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{10}{n \choose k}{D_{n-k}\over n!}.
$$

The remaining work is to estimate $p_n$. We substitute the well known formula 
$$
D_n=\biggl\lfloor {n!\over e}+{1\over 2}\biggr\rfloor,
$$
into the above expression. Denote 
$$m=\sum_{k=0}^{10}{1\over k!}.$$ 
Then $m=9864101/3628800$. It is near to the base of the natural logarithm, of course. Since $x-1<[x]≤x$ holds for all $x$, we can estimate the lower and upper bounds of $p_n$ respectively, in the following way. 
\begin{align}
p_n&<1-{1\over n!}\sum_{k=0}^{10}{n\choose k}\biggl({(n-k)!\over e}-{1\over 2}\biggr)
\le 1-{m\over e}+{5\over (n-10)!}.\\
p_n&\ge 1-{1\over n!}\sum_{k=0}^{10}{n\choose k}\biggl({(n-k)!\over e}+{1\over 2}\biggr)>1-{m\over e}\sim 1.0047766*10^{-8}.
\end{align}

The last value is taken by simply cancelling the last digits of the precise value of $1-m/e$.
When $n\ge 23$, the value of $5/(n-10)!$ is less than $10^{-9}$. So we conclude that 
$$p_n\sim 1.0047766*10^{-8}\qquad\textrm{ for $n\ge 23$}
$$ with error less than $10^{-9}$. For the other cases, that is, $n\le 22$, one may compute the precise value of $p_n$, e.g., 
$$p_{16}={209813\over 20922789888000}\sim 1.002796*10^{-8}.$$
The largest of $p_{11}, p_{12}, \ldots, p_{23}$ is $p_{11}\sim 2.505*10^{-8}$, while the second largest is $p_{13}\sim 1.2686644*10^{-8}$. The sequence $p_n$ converges, rapidly.

Comment: Hi @kwgl. $\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here :)

Comment: Yes thank you Shaum!